# How can I read process memory in chunks and scan for exact address of Values?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, scanning

I have written a simple memory scanner in C++, but it is slow and someone said, that reading chunks of memory would speed it up, but how do I get every correct address ?

Here is a sample source code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

#define CHUNK_SIZE 0x80000
#define MAX_ADDRESS 0x7ffffff

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD pid;
    char buffer[CHUNK_SIZE];
    std::cin >> pid;
    int something;
    int someValue = 0;
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    SIZE_T numberRead;
    if (process)
        printf("opened process.\n");
    else
        printf("could not open process.\n");

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < MAX_ADDRESS; i += CHUNK_SIZE) {
        if (ReadProcessMemory(process, (void*)i, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 
   &numberRead)) {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(buffer); j++)
        {
                someValue = (int)buffer[i];
                if (someValue == 220)
                {
                    printf("found value %d at 0x%x.\n", someValue, i + j);
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Sure I will share my code.

Comment: Well I would ,but I actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to use VirtualQueryEx to loop through all the valid memory and avoid calling ReadProcessMemory on invalid memory

```cpp
while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
{

    if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
    {
        delete[] buffer;
        buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize];

        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, &bytesRead);

        for (int j = 0; j < bytesRead; j++)
        {
                if ((int)buffer[j] == 220)
                {
                    printf("found value %d at 0x%x.\n", someValue, mbi.BaseAddress + j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    addr += mbi.RegionSize;
}

return match;
```

Keep in mind this will return areas of memory where portions of two variables when combined have the same bits as your value in integer representation.  Meaning you can get false positives

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this example. I originally searched for an answer to make my scans speed up a bit, but if ReadprocessMemory reads a larger buffer and processes it later ,my needs are almost completely satisfied. Because it speeds the process up a lot.

Comment: could someone explain how the code has to look like,if you read a chunk of memory into ReadProcessMemory ? Cannot figure it out alone. Perhaps with some code snippet ?

Comment: @DenisMuhic that's what this does, what exactly do you want?

Comment: well ,I cannot get the above code to work.I need some sort of reference ,how it is done  ? Thank you for helping.

Comment: @DenisMuhic Your main question in the original post needs to be updated to be as specific as possible, in a way that we can answer it.   if you edit the question after people have posted answers, give a 1 sentence summary of what you changed about the question, that way people know how to easily update their answers
 https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#define CHUNK_SIZE 0x1

for (DWORD i = 0x000000; i < MAX_ADDRESS; i += CHUNK_SIZE) {
        
        ReadProcessMemory(process, (void*)i, &buffer, sizeof(CHUNK_SIZE), 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < CHUNK_SIZE; j++)
        {
            
            if (buffer[j] == value)
            {
                count++;
                printf("found value %d at 0x%x.\n", buffer[j], i + j);
                //fprintf(f, "0x%x\n", i + j);
                printCheatTable(f,i + j,count);

                results[k] = i + j;
                k++;
            }
            
        }
            
        
    }
```

there must be a problem with this code.
Basically I want to read a chunk of memory into ReadProcessMemory.

There are some modifications to the previous code ,namely "results[k]" array and the function printCheatTable, but which are of no importance to the code.
One more change is that "CHUNK_SIZE" is "0x1" now.